# React 0.13.1 rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this very simple setup that I can’t run using React 0.13.1:

```
var TheApp = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement("div", null)
    )
  }
})

React.render(
  React.createElement(React.createFactory(TheApp)),
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mountComponent' of undefined"

I have read about the changes in React 0.13, but I cannot see why this shouldn’t work.

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/kepihamabi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
React.render(
  React.createElement(React.createFactory(TheApp)),
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

should be

```
React.render(
  React.createFactory(TheApp)(),
  document.getElementById('example')
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The docs/error could probably be more detailed.